# Invertible product of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

1. In the process of proving some theorem, I have assumed that if $A B$
   is invertible, then the matrices $A$ and $B$ are invertible as
   well. However I'm not sure about it. I know that if $A$ and $B$ are
   invertible then $AB$ is also invertible. But does it hold in the
   opposite direction?
2. Is $AB=I$ enough to deduce that $A$ is invertible? Or must I prove that $BA=I$ also holds?

(I'm dealing only with square matrices)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Assuming your matrices are square (the only case in which "invertible" makes sense!), it's true that if $AB$ is invertible, then so are $A$ and $B$. Quick proof: $A$ is invertible if and only if $\det A \ne 0$. And $\det AB = \det A \det B$. You can take it from there.
2. Yes, that's enough. Since $AB = I$, you know that $\det A \det B = 1$, so neither $\det A$ nor $\det B$ can have determinant zero, hence both are invertible (and they are each other's inverses!).

[A commenter notes that if $A$ and $B$ are non-square, then left- and right-invertibility make sense. If that's what you meant, let me know and I'll write more.]

Comment: Well, there's right and left invertibility for non-square matrices.

Comment: @John - thank you so much. I completely forgot about determinants! Very elegant explanation. Have a good day, sir.

Answer (score 1):

If $AB$ are invertible, then $$\det A \cdot \det B =  \det AB  \neq 0$$ so $\det A \neq 0$ and $A$ must be invertible; similarly for $B$.

Comment: ditto for $\det B$. Another way to look at is: LET: $C=AB$. Then, if $C$ is invertible, $C^-1*C=I$. Substitute back in, and figure out what $C^{-1}$ has to be for this to still hold (which it must). $(AB)^{-1}(AB)=I\rightarrow(AB)^{-1}=I*B^{-1}*A^{-1}$ So the solution is:$(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your answer.